# Access to variables between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components **App** and **SomeComponent**.

I want to get access variable in **App** from **SomeComponent**.

**App**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

var places = [];

class App extends Component {

  state = {isLoading:true}
   render(){
bla-bla...}
}

export default App;
```

**SomeComponent**:

```
import React from 'react'
import App from '../App'

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMoint(){
    console.log('Check access places array',App.places)
  }
  render(){
    bla-bla...

  }
}

export { SomeComponent }
```

But its coughed out **places** is *Undefined*, instead of show empty array. Whats wrong here ?
Yes, I've tried different variants... but no success. 
Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you need to `export` place from App

```
export const places = [];
```

And also in child.app

```
import React from 'react'
import { places } from '../App'

class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMoint(){
    console.log('Check access places array',places)
  }
  render(){
    bla-bla...

  }
```

Comment: Ok. But this string: export var places = [];  You assign empty value.  I actually need get current value of places when I'll call this places.

Comment: if your places change in run time and also need to pass to child component, you should pass that as props of that child component.

Comment: I just tested your suggestion... both of them: *export var places = [];* and *export var places *  - the same **undefined**

Comment: add some value to places like `export var places = ['London','Paris'];` like something, then you will able to do that.

Comment: Nope. Just tested. the same - **Undefined**

Comment: changed `var` to `const`, hope it will work. also one concern do this places value populate from state, input or anywhere in run time ?

Comment: @KD if this solve your issue, you can accept this as an answer and also give a up vote to every helping answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way to pass data from a parent component to a child component in React is through props. You can e.g. pass the array as the `places` prop to your `Child` component and access it from `this.props`.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { isLoading: true, places: ['foo', 'bar'] }

  render() {
    return <Child places={this.state.places} />
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Check access places array', this.props.places)
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Child</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry. I know about **props**. I was wrong in questions. I need transfer data between components that not relation **parent-child** but like next each other.

Comment: @kd Ah, I see. Have you tried putting the `places` array in a third separate module, and import that third module into your `App` and `Child` files?

Answer (score 0):

Don't import App into Child. In App, use React's render method with JSX to declare an instance of child. In App's Child JSX, the attributes will become available as "props" within Child. See https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html React expects a programmatic structure that's not as "free" as straight JS, but React then provides a concise, integrated way to make widgets and SPAs.